# I can't feel anything from playing a piano piece anymore

Tags: piano, chopin, expression

I started learning the piano by the age of seven, I remember that my teacher taught me how to build an image about a piece I'm playing, I used to name the pieces myself, draw a painting for each of them and truly enjoy playing the piano.
I haven't played the piano in three years and I've recently started again (I'm 20 years old)
so I tried playing a simple piece like Chopin prelude Op.28 No.4
I've listened to many different versions of this piece played by amazing pianists and I'm always moved when I hear it. However when I'm playing it, every chord feels calculated, it's completely emotionless , once I notice this I feel lost and lose the tempo. Then I try to imitate the versions I've heard and it ends up sounding terrible.
I don't have a piano mentor right now which is why I decided to ask my question here. Maybe I don't have a clear understanding of how to play expressively? I don't know how I can improve so I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Don't try to imitate other people's renditions for the wrong reasons: it would be like trying to feel an emotion by imitating somebody else's reaction to that emotion. Also, don't get confused by what *looks* a "simple" piece, as it might not be (and it often isn't). If you didn't play for some time it's pretty normal that you're more focused on technique, and you also have to consider that you're in a very different age, you can't expect to feel the same things when you're 20 as you did when you were 10: your emotions are much more complex and deeper, and possibly more difficult to "trigger".

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I'll definitely try doing that thanks again !

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is not restricted to playing music, but listening too. It all changes, stuff that used to move you doesn't and other music suddenly moves you deeply. So no wonder that your emotions are different when playing music too. (Especially since you're focused on learning again) In short: it'll come back, but from a different angle.

Comment: There's oft-times, in rehearsal, a piece means absolutely nothing at all; you're just going through it making sure you've got it down pat, no worries, no do-overs. Then you perform it in front of an audience for the first time & nearly come apart because it hits you so hard.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words they motivated me so much thanks again !